# Pass data by UIButton to UITableView on another controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uibutton, plist

I have a AAAViewController with 2 buttons and BBBTableViewController with cells where contents of some plists are to be shown (I work with a storyboard). When button btnAAA is pressed I want to show aaa.plist contents, when btnBBB is pressed then bbb.plist should be displayed in a tableview.
My idea was to assign IBActions to the buttons, store result to NSUserDefaults and the collect it in ViewDidLoad on the next view controller:

```
-(IBAction)pressedAAA {
whatPressed = 1;

//saving my data
NSString *saveWhatPressed = @"AAA";
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:saveWhatPressed forKey:@"savedWhatPressed"];
[defaults synchronize];
}

-(IBAction)pressedBBB {
whatPressed = 2;

//saving my data
NSString *saveWhatPressed = @"BBB";
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:saveWhatPressed forKey:@"savedWhatPressed"];
[defaults synchronize];
}
```

Collection of whatPressed in another controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
//import data from AAA view
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
loadWhatPressed = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedWhatPressed"];

NSLog(@"WhatPressed2: %@", loadWhatPressed);

if (loadwhatPressed == 1) {
    NSString *libraryFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AAA" ofType:@"plist"];
} else {
    NSString *libraryFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BBB" ofType:@"plist"];
}
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

But it failed - the parameter shown in NSLog always showed the previous value of whatPressed.

Next time, I set value of whatPressed in IBAction for each button but I didn't
use NSuserDefaults this time. Then I tried with segue but without any success.

How to do it properly?

Generally:

I need to know in ViewDidLoad in my BBBViewController which button was pressed in AAAViewController. If I knew that then I would use if-else function to set up a proper .plist.

Is it good idea? Or maybe there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use NSUserDefaults to pass data between view controllers. You can set the string in BBBViewController in the prepareForSegue method of AAAViewController

AAAViewController.m:

```
@implementation AAAViewController {
    NSString *libraryFile;
}

-(IBAction)pressedAAA {
    libraryFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AAA" ofType:@"plist"];
}

-(IBAction)pressedBBB {
    libraryFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BBB" ofType:@"plist"];        
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    BBBViewController* vc = (BBBViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.libraryFile = libraryFile;
}
```

BBBViewController.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *libraryFile;
```

**EDIT:**
prepareForSegue will be called before your IBAction methods. To fix this, give each button a unique tag in interface builder and determine which button was pressed inside of the prepareForSegue method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSString *libraryFile;

    switch (tappedButton.tag) {
        case 0:
            libraryFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AAA" ofType:@"plist"];
            break;

        case 1:
            libraryFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BBB" ofType:@"plist"];
            break;

        case 2:
            libraryFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CCC" ofType:@"plist"];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    BBBViewController* vc = (BBBViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.libraryFile = libraryFile;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. I added your code but have an issue. In ViewDidLoad in BBBViewControler to collect my library file I added: myGroup = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:libraryFile]; I am receiving an error: "Use of undeclared identifier libraryFile…" Should I change it into _libraryFile?

Comment: No problem! As for the error, you have three options: 1) Change it to _libraryFile  2) Change it to self.libraryFile  3) Right under the implementation in BBBViewController.m you could synthesize the variable with "@synthesize libraryFile;" and you'll be able to refer to it in the code the same way you currently are

Comment: Yes, I synthesized it. Now, generally it works but I still have a problem with displaying lists from the previous choice (from the button that was pressed 1 time before). And if I press a button for the first time - the list is empty.

Comment: Try moving your code for displaying the lists in BBBViewController.m from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear. viewDidLoad is only called once when the view controller is created but viewWillAppear is called any time the view controller is about to display to the user

Comment: I copied my code to ViewWillAppear, ViewDidAppear and still the same. Everywhere I get for NSLog(@"libFile: %@", libraryFile); :2013-12-14 23:21:14.400 _test3[799:11303] libFile: (null)     when button is pressed for the first time. Thanks for helping anyway, I am very close now and thanks to you I don't use NSUserDefaults. :)

Comment: I'm not sure how you're doing your segue but try doing it programmatically in the IBAction:  `-(IBAction)pressedAAA {
    libraryFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AAA" ofType:@"plist"];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueId" sender:nil];
}`

Comment: It's still the same. It looks like the value from AAA to BBB is passed after BBB view is loaded. If segue is concerned, I use what you proposed: -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    MasterViewController* vc = (MasterViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.libraryFile = libraryFile;
}

Comment: It would be great if you could see it: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3k3z8bnikddm9qk/vzRR2jwMQ8 No worries - if you don't have time, just ignore it. Thnx.

Comment: prepareForSegue was always called before the IBAction methods. To fix this, I first removed the IBAction methods from the buttons and gave each button a unique tag in interface builder. I then moved all of the logic to the prepareForSegue method. We know which button was clicked in that method because we are given the sender. The code can be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/krsewye24l1ru9q/_test3%20copy.zip

Comment: It works fantastically. I've learned a lot from you in this topic. Thank you for your time spent on my question. Cheers :)